# Why is my embeded javascript code not displaying on my WordPress page?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ssl, https, embed

Update:
I have discovered what is impeding the script from displaying.

I am trying to embed a javascript code from an HTTP source into an HTTPS WordPress page.

The error reads:
The page at 'https://www.site*.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://uvlog.com/assets/js/embed.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The site does seem to have an HTTPS as well but there are many required plugins/resources called on that are not over HTTPS.

I have searched all the javascript embed issues here and have been scouring google but have not found anything that addresses this issue.

I have read and followed the WordPress Codex for embedding javascript, uploaded and referenced the js file but I don't know how to get around the HTTPS issue.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You should check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It contains helpful advice on how to word your question to get the best possible response.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript#JavaScript_in_Posts) you would need to have your javascript inside of a separate .js file, and call the file in the content editor, and then call the specific function from your .js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/updatepage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        updatepage();
    //-->
</script>
```

This is most likely done because allowing javascript inside the content editor could bring about some serious security flaws/exploits in the WordPress System.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. I did read the codex as well but it doesn't explain why I am able to add the script to my other sites without adding the separate .js file. I will give it a shot though. Thanks again for the response!